# Pass a List with a custom object type as a parameter

Tags: apex, list, compile-error, mock

I am trying to increase my code coverage, I have only provided parts of my code that I am trying to cover.  I have to create a List to be able to pass over my values into the method. My Errors I have listed below.

- Expecting'<' but was '('
- Invalid type: AccountParameter
- method does not exist or incorrect signature void handleNewAccounts(List) from the type ProcessHandlerShowAccounts

  ```
  @isTest
  public class ProcessHandlerShowAccountsTest {
   @isTest static void testCallout() {

      ProcessHandlerShowAccounts.AccountParameter testAccount = new ProcessHandlerShowAccounts.AccountParameter();
      testAccount.accountId = '0010Z00000schfZZZZ';
      testAccount.name = 'create';
  //I get my 1st two errors here
      LIST<AccountParameter> testActLst = new LIST();
  //I get my last error here
      ProcessHandlerShowAccounts.handleNewAccounts(testActLst);

  }

  }
  ```

Method I am trying to call lives within this Class

```
public class ProcessHandlerShowAccounts 
{
    public class AccountParameter
    {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public Id accountId;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String name;
    }

 public static void handleNewAccounts(AccountParameter [] accountParameters) 
    {

webServiceCallOut(accountParameters[0].accountId,accountParameters[0].name);      
    isAlreadyRun=true;    
    }  

}
```

Comment: Please don't edit the answer back in to the question; this makes the answer seem useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide the fully qualified parameterized type name to the `new` operator:

```
List<AccountParameter> testActLst = new List<AccountParameter>();
```

You can't instantiate the type `List` as such.

That's what these errors are telling you. It found a `(` where it was expecting `<`, from the type name. Then it got confused about the type of your variable, and found there's no method `handleNewAccounts` that takes a `List`, because you cannot have an untyped `List`.

Comment: Let me update my code, does this work?

Comment: My code fails, am i properly adding values within my List?

Comment: As written, your code does not add anything to the List. You must call `List.add()`.

Comment: But dont I have to specify accountId from name? or just do List.add('0010Z00000schfZZZZ')

Comment: You need to add `testAccount` to your list.

Comment: testActLst.add(testAccount) ?

Comment: That is correct.